# E0507 lifetime may not live long enough

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

Goal: Create a function that returns an iterator for all combinations according to nCr.

For example, `let n = 5 and let c = 3`. The iterator should yield slices containing the following data.

```
0 1 2
0 1 3
0 1 4
0 2 3
0 2 4
0 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
```

To challenge myself, as I'm new to rust, I want to do it *without* allocating a new vector for every iteration. Instead, the iterator should modify a vector that it owns and always return a slice over the same vector. Yes, I know the values in the slice will change if the slice is improperly used after subsequent calls to `next` on the iterator.

`````rust
/// Usage: 
/// Let's find all factors of 100. We have obtained all the prime factors earlier.
/// ```
/// let prime_factors = vec![2, 2, 5, 5]; // obtained earlier
/// let mut all_factors = new HashMap::<usize>();
/// all_factors.insert(1);
///
/// // now use every combination of prime factors to find all the factors
/// for c in 1..=prime_factors.len() { 
///     for indexes in combinations(prime_factors.len(), c) {
///         let mut factor = 1;
///         for index in indexes { 
///             factor *= prime_factors[index];
///         }
///         all_factors.insert(factor);
///     }
/// }
///
/// // all_factors now contains [1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]
/// ````
fn combinations<'a>(n: usize, c: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a [usize]> {
    struct State<'a> {
        n: usize,
        c: usize,
        indexes: Vec<usize>, // I think State should OWN this vector
        phantom: PhantomData<&'a ()>, // But I needed a field with a lifetime
    }

    impl<'a> State<'a> {
        fn new(n: usize, c: usize) -> State<'a> {
            State {
                n,
                c,
                indexes: (0..c).collect::<Vec<usize>>(),
                phantom: PhantomData,
            }
        }

        fn update(&mut self) -> bool {
            fn update(indexes: &mut Vec<usize>, at: usize, max: usize) -> bool {
                indexes[at] += 1;
                if indexes[at] == max {
                    if at == 0 {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if !update(indexes, at - 1, max - 1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    indexes[at] = indexes[at - 1] + 1;
                }
                true
            }
            update(&mut self.indexes, self.c - 1, self.c)
        }
    }

    impl<'a> Iterator for State<'a> {
        type Item = &'a [usize];
        fn next(self: &mut State<'a>) -> Option<&'a [usize]> {
            if self.update() {
                Some(&self.indexes[..])
            } else {
                None
            }
        }
    }

    State::new(n, c)
}
`````

Comment: Just FYI, `self: &mut State<'a>` is not idiomatic. You can just say `&mut self`.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm always surprised how beginners reveal the niche-use-case, weird constructs of a language and use them in places where it's completely inappropriate...

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm sure a good portion is just trying to apply patterns that work well in other languages to Rust. Probably the same kind of thing we've all done at one time or another when learning a new language.

Comment: YES!! I c# I can do this incredibly simply by modifying an array and returning the same array reference cast to an IReadOnly interface. To learn more about rust, I'm trying to perform the solution just as elegantly. Even in c#, it's not a "GREAT" idea for a public interface because users might try to collect the results into a list ... and end up with a list of one identical object. But it's perfect for "private" use INSIDE the api's internal code.

Comment: @cdhowie I meant about the `self: &mut State<'a>`.